# Initializing vector with <- 0

Tags: r

In some tutorial code, it is written:

```
## Results vector
results <- numeric()

## Initialize start and end indices
start <- end <- 0

for(index in seq_along(vectors)) {
  values <- vectors[[index]]
  size <- length(values)

  if(size > 0) {
    start <- end + 1
    end <- start + size - 1
    results[start:end] <- values
  }
}
```

Why is this necessary? Why could the coder not do `start <- end <- numeric()?

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** `numeric()` is not the same as `0`, it produces a length-zero numeric vector. Why not try it and see what breaks?

`numeric()` is equivalent to `numeric(0)`, which produces a *length-zero* (empty) numeric vector, while `numeric(1)` would produce a *length-1* numeric vector filled with zeros, i.e.

```
identical(numeric(1),0)
```

is `TRUE`.  In my opinion, `x <- 0` is (much!) clearer than `x <- numeric(1)`.

As for why `start` and `end` need to be initialized to zero:

- `start` doesn't *really* need to be initialized at all
- if `end` is initialized to `numeric()` rather than 0, what happens when we first have to use its value?  The first time `size>0` we execute

```
start <- end + 1
```

If `end` is `numeric(0)` then `start` is also `numeric(0)` I can't explain exactly *why* the result of this operation is defined that way, but from `?Arithmetic`:

> The binary operators return vectors containing the result of the element by element operations.  If involving a zero-length vector the result has length zero.

Then

```
end <- start + size - 1
```

will also result in `numeric(0)`

and

```
results[start:end]
```

will give

```
 Error in start:end : argument of length 0
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. I added more of the code above in the original post.

Now I understand that x <-0 is clearer code and the equivalent of x <-numeric(1). However, I still don't understand why it is needed? Why not just x <- numeric()?

Comment: because (as I said in my answer) (1) the unspecified algorithm you are setting up apparently *requires* `start` and `end` to be initialized to zero; (2) `start <- end <- numeric()`  does something different, i.e. it sets those variables to a length-zero numeric vector.